# I'm having a little probleme with JS and DIV in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, validation

So here is the thing, I'm learning JS and I started to do some simple exercises to get familiar with it, So I tried to do a simple form validation but I'm having a problem with the div that shows errors because they are getting overridden and I want to get some advice to improve this code and make it better if it is possible.

```js
function checkdata() {
    //Acess TextBox Content
    var name1 = document.getElementById("name1").value;
    var name2 = document.getElementById("name2").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;

    //Acess Radio Content
    var tdi = document.getElementById("tdi");
    var tri = document.getElementById("tri");
    var tsi = document.getElementById("tsi");

    //Acess Checkbox
    var ch = document.getElementById("terms").checked;

    //Functions
    if (name1 == "" || name2 == "" || email == "") {
      document.getElementById("errorsdiv").innerHTML = "Those Fields Are Required";

    }
    if ((tdi.checked == false) || (tri.checked == false) || (tsi.checked == false)) {
      document.getElementById("errorsdiv").innerHTML = "You need to check one branch";
    }
    if (ch.checked == false) {
      document.getElementById("errorsdiv").innerHTML = "You need to Agree on our terms";
    }
  }
```

```html
<h1>Form Validation</h1>
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Informations</legend>
    <label for="name1">Enter Your First Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="name1"><br>
    <label for="name2">Enter Your Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="name2"><br>
    <label for="email">Enter Your email</label>
    <input type="text" id="email"><br>
    <label>Choose Your Branch : </label>
    <label for="tdi">TDI</label>
    <input type="radio" name="branch" id="tdi">
    <label for="tri">TRI</label>
    <input type="radio" name="branch" id="tri">
    <label for="tsi">TSI</label>
    <input type="radio" name="branch" id="tsi"><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="terms" id="terms">
    <label for="terms">Agree On Our Terms</label>
  </fieldset><br>
  <input type="button" value="Submit" class="button" onclick="checkdata();">
  <fieldset class="errorsf">
    <legend>Errors</legend>
    <div class="errorsdiv" id="errorsdiv">

    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Use an array: `let errors = [];`. Now push to it: `if (blah) errors.push("Those Fields Are Required");` and finally: `document.getElementById("errorsdiv").innerHTML = errors.join('<br>');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you past your issue with the error messages being overwritten. I changed every occurrence of

```
document.getElementById("errorsdiv").innerHTML =
```

to

```
document.getElementById("errorsdiv").innerHTML +=
```

which prevents `errorsdiv` from being overwritten during each iteration of the `forEach` loop.

I also set `errorsdiv` to an empty state whenever your function is called to prevent the innerHTML from constantly growing after submit attempts.

I also changed the logic in this statement:

```
if ((tdi.checked == false) || (tri.checked == false) || (tsi.checked == false)) {
```

to

```
if ((tdi.checked == false) && (tri.checked == false) && (tsi.checked == false)) {
```

Those need to be `AND` operators instead of `OR` operators.  The way you had it would never return true since only 1 radio button can be checked at any one time.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Form</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script>
    function checkdata() {
      document.getElementById("errorsdiv").innerHTML = "";
      //Acess TextBox Content
      var name1 = document.getElementById("name1").value;
      var name2 = document.getElementById("name2").value;
      var email = document.getElementById("email").value;

      //Acess Radio Content
      var tdi = document.getElementById("tdi");
      var tri = document.getElementById("tri");
      var tsi = document.getElementById("tsi");

      //Acess Checkbox
      var ch = document.getElementById("terms");

      //Functions
      if (name1 == "" || name2 == "" || email == "") {
        document.getElementById("errorsdiv").innerHTML += "<p>First Name, Last Name, and email are Required</p>";

      }
      if ((tdi.checked == false) && (tri.checked == false) && (tsi.checked == false)) {
        document.getElementById("errorsdiv").innerHTML += "<p>You need to check one branch</p> ";
      }
      if (!ch.checked) {
        document.getElementById("errorsdiv").innerHTML += "<p>You need to Agree to our terms</p>";
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Form Validation</h1>
  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Informations</legend>
      <label for="name1">Enter Your First Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="name1"><br>
      <label for="name2">Enter Your Last Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="name2"><br>
      <label for="email">Enter Your email</label>
      <input type="text" id="email"><br>
      <label>Choose Your Branch : </label>
      <label for="tdi">TDI</label>
      <input type="radio" name="branch" id="tdi">
      <label for="tri">TRI</label>
      <input type="radio" name="branch" id="tri">
      <label for="tsi">TSI</label>
      <input type="radio" name="branch" id="tsi"><br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="terms" id="terms">
      <label for="terms">Agree On Our Terms</label>
    </fieldset><br>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" class="button" onclick="checkdata();">
    <fieldset class="errorsf">
      <legend>Errors</legend>
      <div class="errorsdiv" id="errorsdiv">

      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```